# How to dump DWARF information into a file while llvm compiles?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, dwarf

I'd like to know how I might insert some code while llvm compiles IR so that a DWARF information file can be generated.

(I'm not asking for using objdump/llvm-dwarfdump tools after the binary is generated)

Thx in advance.

---

I tried Eli's answer and I got seg fault here, probably I misused it?

```
clang-3.7 -g -emit-llvm -c main.c -o build/main.bc
clang-3.7 -g -emit-llvm -c sum.c  -o build/sum.bc
llvm-link-3.7 build/main.bc build/sum.bc -o build/main.linked.bc
llc-3.7 -split-dwarf Enable build/main.linked.bc -o build/main
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x, int y);

int main()
{
    int r = sum(3, 4);
    printf("r = %d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

sum.c:

```
int sum(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

Seg fault info:

```
0  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332cdf0af8 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 56
1  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332cdeff59
2  libc.so.6        0x00002b332e0bdd40
3  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c86d146 llvm::MCExpr::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::MCAsmInfo const*) const + 134
4  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c86d243 llvm::MCExpr::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::MCAsmInfo const*) const + 387
5  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c84e356
6  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c2f4927 llvm::AsmPrinter::EmitLabelPlusOffset(llvm::MCSymbol const*, unsigned long, unsigned int, bool) const + 87
7  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c2fe6df llvm::AsmPrinter::emitDwarfDIE(llvm::DIE const&) const + 111
8  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c2fe713 llvm::AsmPrinter::emitDwarfDIE(llvm::DIE const&) const + 163
9  libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c325a29 llvm::DwarfFile::emitUnits(bool) + 105
10 libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c323bf0 llvm::DwarfDebug::endModule() + 992
11 libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c2fc251 llvm::AsmPrinter::doFinalization(llvm::Module&) + 513
12 libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c6424b5 llvm::FPPassManager::doFinalization(llvm::Module&) + 69
13 libLLVM-3.7.so.1 0x00002b332c64c09d llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 797
14 llc-3.7          0x0000000000413d1f
15 llc-3.7          0x000000000040ea50 main + 384
16 libc.so.6        0x00002b332e0a8ec5 __libc_start_main + 245
17 llc-3.7          0x000000000040eaa9
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: llc-3.7 -split-dwarf Enable build/main.linked.bc -o build/main
```

Comment: I need to edit the llvm project, to make llvm generate the DWARF file for me at normal compilation process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Adding as an answer because the comment was becoming too long)

FWIW we only support split dwarf on linux right now due to needing an objcopy that supports the use, OS X does it's own thing, and we don't have any solution for windows right now.

That said, for linux:

```
clang -gsplit-dwarf -g foo.c -o foo.o
clang -gsplit-dwarf -g bar.c -o bar.o
```

will produce .dwo files for foo.o (foo.dwo) and bar.o (bar.dwo) respectively.

If you want a dwarf file for the entire program you'll need to use the dwp utility to merge all of the various .dwo files into a single package file. You need to use the clang driver to do the first part since it knows how to invoke objcopy on each individual file, llc doesn't have the knowledge built into it (though it'll produce correct dwarf output, it just won't split it out).

For Mac OSX you can do this via the dsymutil program which comes on the system. clang -g foo.c -o foo will produce a .dSYM directory which has the dwarf for the entire program.

```
    issola:~/tmp> ls -l a.x.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.x   
    -rw-r--r--  1 echristo  5001  9071 Jul 19 20:28  a.x.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.x
```

Comment: can we generate the disassembled (human readable) dwarf file?

Comment: Not particularly, my suggestion there will be to just pipe the output through llvm-dwarfdump (or objdump with a request for the correct sections). Human readable is not something the compiler outputs in this case.

Comment: Why llc does not have the knowledge? It might just need to split the DWARF part of the object into one file.

Comment: Mostly it's the unix philosophy sort of thing. We have different tools for different jobs. It's the job of llc to do code generation into the correct format for the linker etc (also, keep in mind that llc is a developer tool and not an end user tool). It's the job of a dumping tool like objdump, llvm-dwarfdump, etc to turn that into a human readable representation for debugging purposes when working on llvm. There's not much call for end users to want to look at either representation.

If you could describe what you're trying to do or why it might be easier to help you.

Comment: Thx. I'm trying to write the tool myself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile new code at runtime using MCJIT and have DWARF generated for it.

`llc` has the `-split-dwarf` flag. So does Clang (`-gsplit-dwarf`).

Comment: I actually would like to insert code to generate DWARF with normal compile process.

Comment: @Adam: what does it mean? LLVM already generates DWARF if you pass `-g` (`-O0` is recommended too). Can you clarify what you need exactly?

Comment: I want to generate a separate DWARF file with the executable

Comment: @Adam: do you mean DWARF5 split debug info? You can pass `-split-dwarf` to `llc` for that

Comment: I took your advice, however I might misused it. I just edited the post for the new situation.

Comment: @Adam: I'm not sure. it could be that you need to pass `-gsplit-dwarf` when you run clang. It does work for me. Note that you can't expect llc to do the final linking for you. The clang driver invokes `ld` for that.

Comment: Nope, it still does not work... (clang-3.7 -g -gsplit-dwarf -emit-llvm -c) How about implementing it via editing source code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83671/discussion-between-adam-and-eli-bendersky).

Comment: I was going to add a comment about what to do, but it got too long so I just added it as a separate answer elaborating on Eli's.